# How to access bits in mapped memory?

Tags: c, gcc, bit-manipulation, cross-compiling, bit-fields

Imagine! I receive 8 bytes as `uint8_t data[8]` from an IO interface which processes some house automation. These eight bytes need to be interpreted as fallows:

[image: Memory interpretion]

How do I access the right bits?
I thought now about two solutions:

**Solution 1: Defining a struct with some bitfields:**

```
struct data_s {
  uint8_t LightSwitch0:1;
  uint8_t LightSwitch1:1;
  uint8_t LightSwitch2:1;
  uint8_t LightSwitch3:1;
  uint8_t Brightness:4;
  uint8_t Dimmer0;
  uint8_t Dimmer1;
  uint8_t Dimmer2;
  uint8_t Dimmer3;
  uint8_t Dimmer4;
  uint8_t DoorSwitch:1;
  uint8_t Spare:7;
}
```

Next I could simply do a cast and access the structs members according to this example:

```
data_s *foo = data;
foo->LightSwtich1 = FALSE;
foo->Brightness = 7;
//...
```

**Solution 2: Use bitmasks:**

```
data[0] |= 0x02;
data[0] = (data[0] & 0x0F) | (( 7 << 4 ) & 0xF0)
//...
```

Well I know bitfields are compiler depended and are not that portable. Thats why the Solution 2 is often preferred. Nevertheless solution 2 looks much more complicated and is harder to read. Further more it would be much work if the mapped memory has more than eight bytes.

Do I really need to do the solution2? Or I could use the `#pragma reverse_bitfields on` directive to improve the portability of the solution 1? Can I use solution 1 if the code is build just for one target with a cross compiler?

So my question is: **How should I access the right bits?**

Comment: Bitfields are portable and part of C standard. It is a matter of code readability and habits: in my case I prefer bitmasks, but a lot of people prefer bitfileds.

Comment: MISRA used to bar the use of bitfields, I don't know if it still does.

Comment: You could make solution 2 look vastly more readable by using #define macros. You'd end up with the ugly unreadable stuff in just one place which has the added benefit of reducing the amount of work needed to make changes in the future.

Comment: Expanding a little on @ChrisTurner's sugegstion, you can abstract this to a function and use an enum as an argument where each enum value is a mask with a nice name.

Comment: Portability is not the main focus. But it is still important because the Software runs normally on an embedded device and some parts of the code could be run by normal intel based processors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The degree to which bitfields are compiler-dependent has been somewhat exaggerated. They mostly get weird when you use them in a weird way.

In your example, all fields are unsigned and have the same storage type, none of them cross a storage boundary, and there are no unused bits. There is the issue of ordering bits (as you've seen), but in recent years everyone's settled on the same ordering. As far as I know, no current compiler will produce anything not compatible with the IO data you're getting.